# deserializing a JSON list of dictionaries with JavaScriptSerializer

Tags: json, vb.net, serialization

I've been working with deserializing some JSON and when debugging I get the following error in my Immediate Window: "A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll"

Here is the JSON I'm trying to deserialize:

```
{ "Asks":[ [ 919, 11.62026440 ], [ 919.06, 0.07269375 ] ], "Bids":[ [ 901.44, 0.01000050 ], [ 901, 0.25000000 ] ] }
```

My class:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class orderbookJsonDeserializerClass

    Private _asks As List(Of Dictionary(Of Double, Double))
    Public Property asks() As List(Of Dictionary(Of Double, Double))
        Get
            Return _asks
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Dictionary(Of Double, Double)))
            _asks = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Private _bids As List(Of Dictionary(Of Double, Double))
    Public Property bids() As List(Of Dictionary(Of Double, Double))
        Get
            Return _bids
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As List(Of Dictionary(Of Double, Double)))
            _bids = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class
```

My code:

```
Dim js As New JavaScriptSerializer
Dim testObj = js.Deserialize(Of orderbookJsonDeserializerClass)(responseFromServer)
```

When debugging, I get the previously mentioned error when it tries to execute the "Dim testObj = js.Deserialize(Of orderbookJsonDeserializerClass)(responseFromServer)" instruction.

Answer (score 0):

So I think I was making this way too complicated. After making a class of two objects, and then trying different combinations, I finally hit upon the right class to deserialize the JSON to:

```
<Serializable()>
Public Class genericOrderbook
    Public Asks As New List(Of List(Of Double))
    Public Bids As New List(Of List(Of Double))
End Class
```

Now I can loop through and get all the bids and asks, and all that jazz. Problem solved!